# How to add a custom iPhone UI element that is not an IB component?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, android-mapview

I'm trying to create an application that uses the iPhone MapView (under Google Code). I can't figure out how to integrate this thing into my application without handwriting the entire UI, ie not using the IB at all.

How can I use the Interface builder to create all of my menus and such but add the MapView in? Do I need to edit the MapView to make it an IB component?

Thanks!

EDIT:

@pgb

Here is my code, it still just displays a blank UIView, I have connected everything up on the IB side.

```
//
//  NewTestViewController.h
//  NewTest
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewTestViewController : UIViewController {
 UIView* mapPlaceholder;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView* mapPlaceholder;
@end

//
//  NewTestViewController.m
//  NewTest
//

#import "NewTestViewController.h"
#import "MapView.h"

@implementation NewTestViewController
@synthesize mapPlaceholder;



// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        MapView *mapView = [[[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:
        [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
  [mapPlaceholder addSubview:mapView];
    }
    return self;
}


/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [mapPlaceholder.subviews release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

NEVERMIND FIGURED IT OUT THANGS PBG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably create the whole interface in IB, add an empty `UIView` as the placeholder view, and then use `addSubview:` to add the `MapView` instance to the view hierarchy.

Your placeholder view can be defined as an `IBOutlet`, so you can then add the `MapView` from your `UIViewController` instance.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, but I'm not sure how to placeholder something like UIViewController.view["MapViewHolder"]

How do I get access to the UIView which will hold it?

Comment: Add an IBOutlet variable declaration in the `@interface` of the class that your file's owner is an instance of, and connect that outlet to the empty view.

Answer (score 1):

In IB you can add a UIView and then change the type of the view to any custom UIView - I'm assuming MapView subclasses UIView just as MKMapView does...

Comment: Can you explain please? So I would have my IBOutlet UIView* mapView. Then somewhere along the line put something like mapView = [MapView alloc]?

Comment: You don't need to alloc anything.  You would have the IBOutlet be of type MapView (so IBOutlet MapView *mapView) then when the view controller was created with the xib you used, the MapView would be created automatically (note that it has to support construction without arguments, which I can't see why it would not).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create an application that uses the iPhone MapView (under Google Code).

Why not use MapKit? Surely IB comes with an MKMapView in its Library.